# Simple present or present continuous tense for describe a habitual action at spectic time

Tags: tense

I'd like to describe a habit, such as "I am usually asleep around at 3 PM"

"I sleep around at 3PM" doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Can I say "I am sleeping around at 3PM"?

Comment: Why does the former sentence sound incorrect to you?

Comment: "I am usually asleep around 3 PM,"  works just fine.  Just don't use 'around' and 'at' together.  You could also say, "I am usually sleeping at 3 PM".

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was "doesn't sound idiomatic to me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove "around". The first example is best:  "I am usually asleep at 3PM"  (I guess you work shifts?)

"I am sleeping at 3 PM each day", is a possible sentence.  But the adjective "asleep" is better.

You can also say "I go to sleep at about 3PM"

There is an idiom "to sleep around" and it means "have sex with lots of different people"  So **don't** say "I am sleeping around at 3PM" (It means you have sex with lots of people each afternoon)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, no, you cannot use present continuous tense to denote a habitual action.

Habitual actions are represented using **simple present tense**.

> I am usually asleep around 3 PM.

This statement is also correct. You can directly say this sentence or its alternative version using the simple present tense as follows:

> I sleep around 3 pm/ I sleep around 3 in the afternoon.

***NOTE***: "around" will not be followed by "at", since *around* represents an approximate time, whereas *at* represents a specific time. Both the terms cannot be used together.

More examples of simple present tense used in habitual action would be:

- He smokes.
- I get up at 5 am every day.
- He participates in every dance competition.
- She drinks coffee in the afternoon.

For more reference: [Source of examples](https://thebestuknow.com/english-grammar/tense/present/simple/)

Comment: That's a good answer where tense is concerned, but surely, you can't say "around at".  It should just be "around".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I think present continuous tense can be used to describe temporary or new habits, at least according to google. And my American colleagues sometimes use the tense that way.